# concatenating short noise sequences

Tags: matlab, audio

I'm trying to merge 2 identical audio files. The Audio file is nothing more than white noise generated using MATLAB commands

```
block_len = 4096;
Y = wgn(block_len, 1, 5, 120, 'dBm', 'real');
```

Rather than generating a longer block of data, i would like to make a longer file by concatenating the block of 4096 samples.

Therefore I tried a simple,

```
datat = [Y;Y;Y;Y;Y];
soundsc(datat)
```

The output file is not smooth enough. There is an audible periodic pattern that indicates the multiple 'Y' segments. I believed this could be due to the imperfect combination at the beginning and End of each Y segment.

Therefore I added the lines

```
Y(1) = 0;
Y(end) = 0;
```

Concatenating after these still does not have a smoothness to it. I searched on stackoverflow and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012679/how-to-smoothly-connect-two-signals-in-matlab).

I tried the code based on the link above. I still can't get a smoothness to the white noise. What other methods can i try to make the sound as smooth as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marcus I took your advice based on the correlation. So i modified the Y segments to generate different white noise at each instance. Here is the MATLAB code for the same.

```
clc;clear all;close all;

block_len = 4096;
YY = wgn(block_len, 1, 50, 10, 'dBm', 'real');
XY = wgn(block_len, 1, 50, 10, 'dBm', 'real');
ZY = wgn(block_len, 1, 50, 10, 'dBm', 'real');
VY = wgn(block_len, 1, 50, 10, 'dBm', 'real');
S1 = YY/max(YY);
S2 = XY/max(XY);
S3 = ZY/max(ZY);
S4 = VY/max(VY);

% S1 = rand(1000,1);
% S2 = rand(1000,1) + 1;

%\\ cross-fade over last 200 elements
n = 256;
nob = 2;

W = linspace(1,0,n)';                                    %'

S1(end-n+1:end) = S1(end-n+1:end).*W;
S2(1:n) = S2(1:n).*(1-W);
S2(end-n+1:end) = S2(end-n+1:end).*(W);

S12 = zeros(size(S1,1) + size(S2,1) + size(S2,1) + size(S2,1) - n, 1);
S12(1:size(S1,1)) = S1;
S12((block_len*2)-n-size(S1,1)+1:(block_len*2)-n) = S12((block_len*2)-n-size(S1,1)+1:(block_len*2)-n) + S2;

startpt = (block_len*3)-(2*n)-size(S1,1)+1;
endpt = (block_len*3)-(2*n);
S12(startpt:endpt) = S12(startpt:endpt) + S3;

startpt = (block_len*4)-(3*n)-size(S1,1)+1;
endpt = (block_len*4)-(3*n);
S12(startpt:endpt) = S12(startpt:endpt) + S4;

soundsc(S12)
```

Now the periodic pattern is not audible. Therefore it was that correlation that was to blame.

@Bob I also changed

```
  block_len = 16384
```

and

```
startpt = (block_len*3)-(2*n)-size(S1,1)+1;
endpt = (block_len*3)-(2*n);
S12(startpt:endpt) = S12(startpt:endpt) + S2;

startpt = (block_len*4)-(3*n)-size(S1,1)+1;
endpt = (block_len*4)-(3*n);
S12(startpt:endpt) = S12(startpt:endpt) + S2;
```

at which point, the periodic pattern wasn't noticeable anymore. So both your explanations hold true.

Answer (score 1):

> Rather than generating a longer block of data, i would like to make a longer file by concatenating the block of 4096 samples.

Bad idea. That means your noise becomes perfectly correlated with a period of 4096 samples, and that's definitely not white noise anymore, and you'll stand a realistic chance of noticing that audibly; depending on the sampling rate, that $\frac{f_\text{sample}}{4096}$ might be a directly audible frequency.

A lot of signal processing algorithms are sensitive to periodicity, so: really, don't do that.

By the way, you might be clipping. Gaussian noise amplitude is unbound, but your sound card's acceptable numeric range very much is.

> The output file is not smooth enough. There is an audible periodic pattern that indicates the multiple 'Y' segments.

Which was predictable, because that's exactly what you've been asking it to generate.

> I believed this could be due to the imperfect combination at the beginning and End of each Y segment.

No, this was you; you introduced periodicity, and your human sound system notices that. Congratulations! Your hearing is functional :)

You using a "blend over" technique on white noise says you  haven't really thought about what *white* means: it means that there's no correlation between successive samples. Thus, if you concatenate two different, uncorrelated white noise sequences, you get a white noise sequence.

If you concatenate the same sequence, you get something periodic.

What you need to do is  generate white noise of the desired length instead of concatenating short sequences. You forgot to mention why you would even want to do that, because (haven't benchmarked matlab) white noise generation should really be fast.

Comment: White noise, by definition, means equal intensities at different frequencies. If we adhere to this definition, how can concatenating two same blocks of white noise change anything? The spectral content hasn't changed, has it?

Comment: White noise, by definition, is uncorrelated (which is exactly the same as saying the expectation of the noise power spectral density is a constant): So yes, the spectral content very much changes. As explained in length, you introduce periodicities. So, afterwards, you are correlated, and you see exactly that in the PSD; it's pretty obviously no longer white.

Comment: @dsp_user remember the definition of "spectrum": It's the fourier transform of the autocorrelation function of a stochastic signal. Now, your stochastic signal repeats every 4096 samples, meaning you get a strong peak in the autocorrelation function every 4096 sampling duration, which, after Fourier Transformation, yields a peak at a frequency (and its negative counterpart); it **can't** be white anymore.

Comment: the problem is I still hear the concatenated signal as white noise. It takes probably a minute or so to simulate this in Audacity and I can't hear any audible anomaly (sorry couldn't find a better word) in the signal generated (but granted I didn't concatenate two 4096 sample blocks).

Comment: @dsp_user you might simply have a different noise realisation than OP – op describes distinguishable "repeating" features. And, OP doesn't seem to be randomly seeding their noise generator, thus always producing the same noise.

Comment: or perhaps he's even doing something wrong that he isn't aware of. Lets leave it here :)

Answer (score 1):

We discussed this phenomenon [on the music-dsp mailing list in May 2014](https://music.columbia.edu/pipermail/music-dsp/2014-May/thread.html#72423).

For long enough a period, the audible repetition is not directly about the frequency spectrum but that instances of white noise are not white but usually contain distinct features or patterns that can be learned and then recognized in the later periods. In some instances, there will be more distinct features than in others. An interesting follow-up question would be, how can we create noise that is as featureless as possible? Spectrogram smoothing works to some extent, but I don't think it's the last word.

Clips of white noise can be readily concatenated, because white noise has zero autocorrelation at non-zero time lags. Other types of noise would require more gentle splicing.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to assemble a very large number of these segments and then take the FFT of the entire signal, you would see that you have a series of spectral sticks every FS/4096 hz, with nothing in between, because the signal you have made by concatenation is periodic.
However your ear does not have an infinite analysis window, so once your block length is much longer than, say, 50ms, you shouldn’t be able to hear the effects of concatenation. If your FS is set to 48khz, then 4096 samples represents about 85ms in time. Therefore I’m surprised you can hear any effect.  What is your sample-rate? If it’s very high then the repetition rate will be faster and may be audible.
Also you might try removing the mean from your 4K noise segment before concatenation (although in theory this should not be necessary)

Bob

Comment: He doesn't say he hears the repetitivity as a "tonal experience", but as repeating pattern - which fits nicely into your explanation.